# Checklist for drupal developers to be ready for drupal 8

Tags: 8

As Drupal 8 will be using symphony framework, what will be the best learning path for developers to get ready to adopt for Drupal 8.

Comment: This is a broad and subjective question: The best path depends from your knowledge of the frameworks Drupal 8 includes. What is best for you is not the best for another person.

Comment: Broad strokes it's quite simple - Read up on Symfony dependency injection and the service container, read through the Drupal change records to see what's changed, clone the repo, and step through a few page requests to see what goes on under the hood. Then port a couple of your favourite modules over, just for fun, and you're ready for D8 :) But that's just my way of doing it, as @kiamlaluno notes it's quite a tailored process, depends what you already know

Comment: @kiamlaluno I was expecting quick pointers as answer ,yes question might be too broad to answer if answered in that way but suggestions as starters would be great to pick the right path.

Comment: @arpitr These are some of the things you'll need to be comfortable with: DI, service container, PSR-0 (and maybe PSR-4), Composer, OO architecture (not just the odd class like in d7, if inheritance or polymorphism aren't familiar, learn them now), Symfony routes, Annotations, YAML, TWIG, and a bunch of other things that probably aren't coming to mind right now

Comment: Answers are not supposed to give suggestions, but answer the question. That is why too broad questions are not acceptable, on Stack Exchange sites: The reason why you accept an answer needs to be evident in the answer itself, and it should not be an subjective reason you only know. Plus, questions are for future users too, not only the user who asked the question; this is the reason why highly subjective questions are not a good fit for Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Here's a quick pointer. @jmolivas is collection a great set of resource to get into Drupal 8 https://github.com/jmolivas/drupal8-links

Comment: @jonhattan Great collection of links, thanks for those